# Firebase Cloud Messaging Node.JS Notification Not receiving

Tags: node.js, post, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I programmed a Node.JS Server with FCM and POST Protocol and my Client app is made with Swift code.

In Terminal, It prints success code like this

```
id=0:1476620858011270%00f7ba1cf9fd7ecd
```

But In my Client App, there is no notification. So I tried with the notification tab in my Firebase Console, and it worked very well.

This is my header in my server file

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'key=<Server Key>',
  'project_id': '<Project ID>'
}
```

and This is my Request Code

```
    request({
  headers: headers,
  url: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
  method: "POST",
  form: {
    "notification" :{
      "title": "titie",
      "body": "body"
    },

    "content-available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "to": "<Firebase Token>"
  }
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
```

Comment: Please, NEVER disclose your Server key to the public. It should always be kept secret. With that said, have you tried only using `priority`? Try removing `content_available`.

Comment: Well, It Doesn't work and there is no difference